# Delegatecall failing

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, proxy-contracts

I have this second-layer `delegatecall` (delegatecall on a contract that already did delegatecall) that continues to fail even after checking all the main reasons why it could fail (storage layout, uint alias, contract, etc.).

And when I switch from `delegatecall` to `call`, it runs perfectly (but I need delegatecall).

I simplified the troubling function to a simple `getHi()`/`getHello()` (no args) with a `console.log` in the body, but it still fails. This is a brief summary of the contracts involved in order to show the basic setup:

(I wouldn't bother too much with the first contract. It's just a proxy that redirect calls)

```js
contract Diamond {
   AppStorage s;

   fallback() external payable { 
        LibDiamond.DiamondStorage storage ds;
        bytes32 position = LibDiamond.DIAMOND_STORAGE_POSITION;
        assembly {
            ds.slot := position
        }
        address facet = ds.facets[msg.sig];
        require(facet != address(0), "Diamond: Function does not exist");
        assembly {
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), facet, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
            switch result
                case 0 {
                    revert(0, returndatasize())
                }
                default {
                    return(0, returndatasize())
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
contract FacetX {
   AppStorage s;

   using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

   function getHi() public {
        console.log(s.facetY); //-----> logs the address of FacetY
        (bool success, ) = s.facetY.delegatecall( //-----> with `call`, runs smoothly
            abi.encodeWithSignature('getHello()')
        );
        require(success, 'failed'); //-----> fails with this error
    }
}
```

```js
contract FacetY {
   AppStorage s;

   using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

   function getHello() public view {
        console.log('hello world'); //-----> never gets logged
    }
}
```

`AppStorage` is just a struct with all the state vars in a separate file that I import on each contract. Something like:

```js
struct AppStorage {
   address facetY;
   address usdt;
   ...
}
```

They're defined elsewhere without issues. That's why `s.facetY` logs the address of FacetY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

`delegatecall` forwards `msg.value` (besides `msg.sender`).

I was calling the proxy while sending Ether and even though my functions don't handle Ether per se, I still needed to label them as `payable` (both functions in the second and third contract). Otherwise, the tx will fail.

So by adding `payable` to `getHi()` and `getHello()`, the problem was fixed.